# Visual studio code - lldb debugging rust, change the project directory

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

Hi I have the following state:

The cargo rust project: `/Users/daniel1302/www/aws-alarm/`
The workspace dir: `/Users/daniel1302/www

I have the following debugging configuration:

```
{
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "rust/aws-alarm",
            "cwd": "/Users/daniel1302/www/aws-alarm/",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--lib"
                ],
            },
            "program": "${cargo:program}",
            "args": [],
            "env": {
                "AWS_PROFILE": "sf_MFA",
                "AWS_REGION": "us-east-1"
            },
        }
```

When I am starting the project debugging I can see:

```
Running `cargo build --lib --message-format=json`...
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/Users/daniel1302/www/releases` or any parent directory
```

The issue is, that cwd directive does not change the project directory.

Do you know How can I change the cargo project directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found workaround by setting cargo arg `--manifest-path`:

```json
"configurations": [
{
...
    "cargo": {
        "args": [
           "build",
           "--bin=importer",
           "--package=cprices",
           "--manifest-path=${workspaceFolder}/cprices/Cargo.toml"
        ],
...
```